# Slow running PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am currently trying to migrate a system to postgres and I am unfortunately not able to understand why a specific query is running so incredibly slow. Both in Transact-SQL and Oracle the same query runs in under 200ms. First things first though, I have a big table with **14.000.000 entries** currently which only gets bigger and bigger. Furthermore the table itself has **54 columns** meaning that we have quite the sum of data.

The table has a rather straight forward structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE logtable (
    key varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    column1 int4 NULL,
    entrytype int4 NULL,
    column2 int4 NULL,
    column3 int4 NULL,
    column4 int4 NULL,
    column5 int4 NULL,
    column6 int4 NULL,
    column7 varchar(128) NULL,
    column8 varchar(2048) NULL,
    column9 varchar(2048) NULL,
    column10 varchar(2048) NULL,
    ...
    timestampcol timestamp NULL,
    column48 timestamp NULL,
    column49 timestamp NULL,
    column50 timestamp NULL,
    column51 timestamp NULL,
    column52 int4 NULL,
    column53 int4 NULL,
    column54 varchar(20) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (key)
);
```

We also have a few predefined indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON logtable USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON logtable  USING btree (archiveinterval);
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON logtable  USING btree (archivestatus);
CREATE INDEX idx4 ON logtable  USING btree (entrytype);
CREATE INDEX idx5 ON logtable  USING btree (column34);
CREATE INDEX idx6 ON logtable  USING btree (timestampcol);
```

Now the actual query that I perform is the following:

```
SELECT column1,..,column54
FROM logtable
where ((entrytype = 4000 or entrytype = 4001 or entrytype = 4002) and (archivestatus <= 1))
order by timestampcol desc;
```

This results in roughly 500K selected items.
When establishing the connection, i also pass ***defaultRowFetchSize=5000*** so the resultset doesn't try to get the full result set. As mentionend before, the same query takes about 200 ms in Oracle and MSSQL. Which leaves me wondering, what is exactly going on here. When I add a **LIMIT 100**, it reduces the query performance to 100 ms.
Now I've already set these variables higher since I've seen these in multiple forum threads:

```
maintenance_work_mem    1GB
shared_buffers  2GB
```

I've also tried understanding the **explain analyze** resulting from the query. As I see it, it takes about 49 s just trying to bitmap heap scan.

```
Gather Merge  (cost=459158.89..507278.61 rows=412426 width=2532) (actual time=57323.536..59044.943 rows=514825 loops=1)
  Output: key, column2 ... column54
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=1411 read=292867
  ->  Sort  (cost=458158.86..458674.40 rows=206213 width=2532) (actual time=57243.386..57458.979 rows=171608 loops=3)
        Output: key, column2 ... column54
        Sort Key: logtable.timestampcol DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60266kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 57572kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 57878kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1411 read=292867
        Worker 0: actual time=57218.621..57449.331 rows=168159 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=470 read=94622
        Worker 1: actual time=57192.076..57423.333 rows=169151 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=461 read=95862
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on logtable (cost=9332.66..439956.67 rows=206213 width=2532) (actual time=1465.971..56452.327 rows=171608 loops=3)
              Output: key, column2 ... column54
              Recheck Cond: ((logtable.entrytype = 4000) OR (logtable.entrytype = 4001) OR (logtable.entrytype = 4002))
              Filter: ((logtable.entrytype = 4000) OR (logtable.entrytype = 4001) OR ((logtable.entrytype = 4002) AND (logtable.archivestatus <= 1)))
              Heap Blocks: exact=101535
              Buffers: shared hit=1397 read=292867
              Worker 0: actual time=1440.278..56413.158 rows=168159 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=463 read=94622
              Worker 1: actual time=1416.245..56412.907 rows=169151 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=454 read=95862
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=9332.66..9332.66 rows=500289 width=0) (actual time=1358.696..1358.697 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=6 read=1322
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx4(entrytype)  (cost=0.00..1183.80 rows=66049 width=0) (actual time=219.270..219.271 rows=65970 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (logtable.entrytype = 4000)
                          Buffers: shared hit=1 read=171
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx4(entrytype)  (cost=0.00..3792.43 rows=211733 width=0) (actual time=691.854..691.855 rows=224437 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (logtable.entrytype = 4001)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=576
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx4(entrytype)  (cost=0.00..3985.24 rows=222507 width=0) (actual time=447.558..447.558 rows=224418 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (logtable.entrytype = 4002)
                          Buffers: shared hit=3 read=575
Planning Time: 0.562 ms
Execution Time: 59503.154 ms
```

When I do the same query WITHOUT the Order by, the query finishes in about 1.6 s which seems reasonable enough. When I take away the where clause, the query finishes in 86 ms which is due to my idx6.

I am kinda out of ideas. I've tried multiple indexes. Some composite indexes like = (entrytype, archivestatus, timestampcol) in different orders and with DESC. Is there something else I could try?

**UPDATE:**

Since a few of you asked, here i the query execution plan for Oracle. As I said, the literal same statement witht he same indexes runs in 0.2 seconds in oracle whereas it needs about 30-50 s in postgres.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                         |  6878 |  2491K|  2147   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                         |                         |  6878 |  2491K|  2147   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   CONCATENATION                        |                         |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | logtable                |   712 |   257K|   168   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | entrytype               |   712 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    INLIST ITERATOR                     |                         |       |       |            |          |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| logtable                |  6166 |  2233K|  1433   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | idx_entrytype           |  6166 |       |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As someone mentionend, I had tried **set enable_bitmapscan to off** before but it didn't quite help. It had an impact, making the query faster, but it didn't exactly help to the point where I would consider using it.

```
Gather Merge  (cost=543407.97..593902.72 rows=432782 width=2538) (actual time=26207.686..27543.386 rows=515559 loops=1)
  Output: column1 ... column54
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=258390 read=147694 dirtied=3 written=1
  ->  Sort  (cost=542407.94..542948.92 rows=216391 width=2538) (actual time=26135.793..26300.677 rows=171853 loops=3)
        Output: column1 ... column54
        Sort Key: logtable.timestampcol DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 61166kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 56976kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 57770kB
        Buffers: shared hit=258390 read=147694 dirtied=3 written=1
        Worker 0: actual time=26100.640..26257.665 rows=166629 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=83315 read=48585 dirtied=2
        Worker 1: actual time=26102.323..26290.745 rows=169509 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=84831 read=48779
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on logtable  (cost=0.00..523232.15 rows=216391 width=2538) (actual time=3.752..25627.657 rows=171853 loops=3)
              Output: column1 ... column54
              Filter: ((logtable.entrytype = 4000) OR (logtable.entrytype = 4001) OR ((logtable.entrytype = 4002) AND (logtable.archivestatus <= 1)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 4521112
              Buffers: shared hit=258294 read=147694 dirtied=3 written=1
              Worker 0: actual time=1.968..25599.701 rows=166629 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=83267 read=48585 dirtied=2
              Worker 1: actual time=3.103..25604.552 rows=169509 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=84783 read=48779
Planning Time: 0.816 ms
Execution Time: 27914.204 ms
```

Just to clarify, my hope is that there is some kind of configuration, index or something else I've missed to put. Since we have a generic mechanism creating this query, it would be quite ugly to implement a database specific query JUST for this specific table. It's our biggest table by far containing log entries from throughout the system. (I don't exactly like this design but it is what it is) There must be a reason why Postgres in particular, is that much slower compared to other databases when handling big data.

As multiple users pointed out, the condition should be:

```
where ((entrytype = 4000 or entrytype = 4001 or entrytype = 4002) and (archivestatus <= 1))
```

NOT

```
where (entrytype = 4000 or entrytype = 4001 or entrytype = 4002 and (archivestatus <= 1))
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's normal. You read a lot of data from disk, and they are spread all over the table. Perhaps `CLUSTER`ing the table on one of the indexes can help a little bit.

Comment: Are you sure? I doubt that SQL Server (or Oracle) will retrieve 500k [massive] rows in under 200ms. Maybe you can see the first rows in that time frame, but not the whole thing.

Comment: @TheImpaler well In both cases I only need a subset. In Oracle (SQLDeveloper) I get the first 200 rows in 0.298 seconds. In postgres it is also 200 (DbBeaver). I don't have SQL Server set up right now but I can assure you, that oracle only needs that much for the same query. Internally both JDBC drivers obviously limit the result set fetch size (defaultRowFetchSize - postgres) and (fetchSize - oracle). I'm not exactly sure how the respective databases resolve the query internally so I can't tell you anything regarding that.

Comment: If you want to compare the execution plans from two different DBMS, you need to look at the execution plans from both of them, not just one of them.

Comment: First VACUUM ANALYZE the table and see if that changes anything.  If it doesn't, then `set enable_bitmapscan=false` and see what plan that leads to.

Comment: You plan is fetching 500,000 rows.  How is PostgreSQL supposed to know you only need 200, if you don't tell it that?

Comment: OK, so do you only need the first 200 rows, or all half a million of them? If you only need 200, then add `LIMIT 200` to your query and that would probably speed up the query.

Comment: With respect, there's something you have not told us about your requirement. How many of those rows do you actually need? Please [edit] your question. One of the points of SQL databases is to allow rapid retrieval of small subsets of rows from large tables. The various servers have syntax features (like `LIMIT 1000` or `SELECT TOP (1000)`) to help the query planning modules work out the best way to get what you want. You may be defeating the optimization.

Comment: So without going into further detail, what I understand from oracle and postgres is, that they create a resultset which is a resultiterator of sorts. It has pointers TO the results. Meaning in either case, it should actually INSTANTLY load all 500.000 results. I know this is the case for oracle. Postgres I'm not so sure anymore. And then depending on the fetchsize parameter, the resultset is returning the entries based on that (1000 or 200 at a time). I know that LIMIT would be technically better but I just want to understand why the same query is so much slower.

Comment: Your where condition looks strange. It is equivalent to `where entrytype in (4000,4001) or (entrytype = 4002 and archivetype <= 1)` is that really what you mean?

Comment: the database is on ssd drive or hdd? check ‘random_page_cost’ and ‘seq_page_cost’ configuration parameters. If running on ssd maybe you can set 'random_page_cost' to a lower value (see [link](https://amplitude.engineering/how-a-single-postgresql-config-change-improved-slow-query-performance-by-50x-85593b8991b0))

Comment: It confirmed, it is running on an ssd and the parameter did have an impact on the performance, unfortunately not enough. It went from 40-60 s to now 10-15 s. This is definitely better for now and a good parameter, it must be possible to tune this query even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing different versions of postgres, 12.6 and 13.2 on Windows and even 13.2 on Linux docker, I could never reproduce the issue. We concluded that it must have been due to the environment acting up. Either that or Disk or Network issues. Either way, this had was no Postgres error.

Answer (score 2):

Index lookups are expensive, so sql engine tends to use pk scan, instead of indexes, when retrieving many columns.

You can give a try with a composite index on entrytype+archivestatus (in this order) to extract relevant keys and then rejoin main table to get all columns.

Keep also the index on `timestampcol` for ordering the results.

```
SELECT column1,..,column54
FROM (
    SELECT key _key
    FROM logtable
    where entrytype IN (4000, 4001, 4002) and (archivestatus <= 1)       
) X
JOIN logtable L ON X._key = L.key
order by timestampcol desc;
```

Another option is to use the `UNION` operator to try to force the use of index on a reduced partition

```
SELECT column1,..,column54
FROM (
    SELECT key _key
    FROM logtable
    where (entrytype = 4000) and (archivestatus <= 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT key _key
    FROM logtable
    where (entrytype = 4001) and (archivestatus <= 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT key _key
    FROM logtable
    where (entrytype = 4002) and (archivestatus <= 1)

) X
JOIN logtable L ON X._key = L.key
order by timestampcol desc;
```

Results may vary depending on many factors, so you have to try the best approach for your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the approaches. Unfortunately both queries run even slower than my statement. The first took about 64 seconds and the second took about 119 seconds. Doesn't seem to be actually helping.

Comment: The original condition is different because the condition on the archivestatus is only applied to the entrytype 4002 not all of them.  The equivalent would be a union of two select using `select where entrytype in (4000,4001) union all select ... where entrytype = 4002 and archivestatus <= 1`  - and that is pretty much what Oracle's optimizer is doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, I missed the closed parenthesis after the AND condition instead of before, let's hear from op if it was an error or what

Comment: Yeah that's an error on my part, I will update the question, my bad.